# converting more than one returns from class component to functional component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function

I'm trying to convert a react native based class to functional based class and i run into a class component that has 2 returns statement and i have no clue how to convert it to the functional component. This is the class component. Note that I'm omitting codes not important

```
    export default class Card extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    shadow: true,
    border: true,
    title: null,
  }

  renderHeader = () => {
    const { title } = this.props;
    if (!title) return null;

    return (
      <Block row space="between" style={styles.header}>
        <Text caption>{title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          {/* <Icon options /> */}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Block>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { shadow, border, style, children, ...props } = this.props;
    const cardStyles = [
      styles.card,
      shadow && styles.shadow,
      border && styles.border,
      style,
    ];

    return (
      <Block style={cardStyles} {...props}>
        {this.renderHeader()}
        {children}
      </Block>
    )
  }
}
```

This is what I have come up with

```
const Card = title => {
  static defaultProps = {
    shadow: true,
    border: true,
    title: null,
  }

  renderHeader = () => {
    const { title } = title;
    if (!title) return null;
  }
  renderHeader = () => {
    const { title } = this.props;
    if (!title) return null;
  }
  const { shadow, border, style, children, ...props } = this.props;
  const cardStyles = [
    styles.card,
    shadow && styles.shadow,
    border && styles.border,
    style,
  ];

  return [
    <Block row space="between" style={styles.header}>
        <Text caption>{title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          {/* <Icon options /> */}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Block> <
    Block style = { cardStyles } { ...props } > { renderHeader() } { children } <
    /Block>
  ]
}
```

Note that when I run the code, it didn't display any error, also note that before asking this question, I have surfed here and the search engines but didn't find any suitable answers

Answer (score 1):

All the functional components gets an argument a prop object . so we can de-structure and assign the default values . So your code

```
 static defaultProps = {
    shadow: true,
    border: true,
    title: null,
  }
```

is now changed to

```
const Card = ({
  shadow = true,
  border = true,
  title = null,
  style,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
```

The methods in the class components are changed to functions in functional components . so you can change your `renderHeader` as

```
const renderHeader = () => {
    .... 
  };
```

Since your renderHeader is just another function , you can remove the `this` when calling it

```
 {renderHeader()}
```

**Converted Component**

```
const Card = ({
  shadow = true,
  border = true,
  title = null,
  style,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const renderHeader = () => {
    if (!title) return null;

    return (
      <Block row space="between" style={styles.header}>
        <Text caption>{title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>{/* <Icon options /> */}</TouchableOpacity>
      </Block>
    );
  };

  const cardStyles = [
    styles.card,
    shadow && styles.shadow,
    border && styles.border,
    style,
  ];

  return (
    <Block style={cardStyles} {...props}>
      {renderHeader()}
      {children}
    </Block>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

**Reference**

[Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)